# middleware laravel not work in Route::any

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

I was a ASP.NET MVC developer and now I try to learn Laravel Framework but I have problem with Middleware.
We have a default route in ASP.NET MVC and this route help us to know witch controller or action in use now and this a default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

We use some key word in our controller for control our middleware for example :

```
[Authentication]
public class HomeController : BaseController {
```

I try to create this route in Laravel, after many try I create this route and this is my route

```
Route::any('/{controller?}/{action?}', function($controller = "", $action = ""){
    $app = app();

    if( empty($action) && empty($controller) ){
        $controller = "Home";
        $action .= "Index";
    }

    if( isset($controller) && empty($action) ){
        $action .= ucfirst($controller);
        $controller = "Home";
    }

    $action = strtolower(request()->getMethod()) . ucfirst($action);
    $controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\\' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';

    if( ! class_exists($controller) ){
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $controller = $app->make($controller);

    if ( ! method_exists( $controller, $action ) ){
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    return $controller->callAction($action, [request()]);
});
```

For set middleware I try in controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

but middleware not work.

Comment: is the method fired?

Comment: Just a sidenote, having multiple optional URL parameters like `{controller?}/{action?}` is a bad idea; if you have `/one/two` it'll work, but if you have `/two`, and expect `two` to be the `action`, it won't work. That, or you'll have to put `/null/two` (or `/0/two`, etc) and handle "falsy" parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware must be attached to the route, so the simplest solution is to just add

```
->middleware('auth');
```

after your route function eg:

```
Route::any('/{controller?}/{action?}', function($controller = "", $action = ""){
// your code 
})->middleware('auth');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, this will be work but I want dynamically in my code and changed in anther Controller

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the middleware doesn't work. The router needs to create an instance of the Controller to be able to get the middleware that could be defined in its constructor to build the middleware stack for the Request to go through **before** the route is dispatched through the pipeline to the destination. The Controllers themselves do not run middleware. The router knows nothing about what you are doing inside your route Closure definition. Everything regarding middleware happens before you get to the action of the route. Once you are in that action you have already passed through the middleware stack (you can't add to it now).

In your example the route isn't going to a controller it is a Closure based route. And there is no middleware defined for that route.

Laravel removed "implicit Controllers" awhile ago in favor of explicitly defining your routes.

You are making your own routing logic inside of a route that is handled by a router after the request has already passed through the entire middleware stack. The only possible middleware that could be used would be any middleware directly assigned to this route you have defined.